# Parsing JSON - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, json

I am trying to parse JSON, using Objective-C This is the NSLog Echoed with my current code.

```
   {
    KnowledgeBaseEntry =         {
        AllowBotAccess = 1;
        FulltextSearch = 1;
        GroupId = "";
        Id = 611552aea1fe4d789e31133d3ee77f35;
        IsPublic = 1;
        Languages = "";
        OwnerId = 8c427d5;
        ParentId = 1;
        ShortcutWord = "";
        Tags = "";
        Title = "Another Test Cell";
        Type = 1;
        Value = "This <BR>Is<BR>testing";
    };
},
    {
    KnowledgeBaseEntry =         {
        AllowBotAccess = 1;
        FulltextSearch = 1;
        GroupId = "";
        Id = fc4f1a90243246bb93641b0c8db689b9;
        IsPublic = 1;
        Languages = "";
        OwnerId = 8c427d5;
        ParentId = 1;
        ShortcutWord = "";
        Tags = "";
        Title = "Cydo Error 2";
        Type = 1;
        Value = "content<BR><BR>this is contenty";
    };
},
    {
    KnowledgeBaseEntry =         {
        AllowBotAccess = 1;
        FulltextSearch = 1;
        GroupId = "";
        Id = bd057d5443194d7a98c2398e07de919e;
        IsPublic = 1;
        Languages = "";
        OwnerId = 8c427d5;
        ParentId = 1;
        ShortcutWord = "";
        Tags = "";
        Title = testkb2;
        Type = 1;
        Value = "test content!";
    };
}
```

)

I need to use the Title to grab what is in the Value so I can display in app. I can access the Title Var but I have no idea how to match the two to NSLog the Value. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the current code:

```
        NSData *rGeniusData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
                              [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://jbbar.ml/rgenius/ipapi.php"]];
                              //Parse The JSON
        NSError *error;
        NSMutableDictionary *allKB = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:rGeniusData
                                                          options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                          error:&error];

        NSArray *kb = allKB[@"KnowledgeBaseEntries"];NSLog(@"AboveDP= %@",  kb);
```

Comment: what you want? You want to match a value of you want to pick your value from nslog?

Comment: I have imported the Titles into a UITableView

Comment: I have imported the Titles into a UITableView and on select, I want to be able to use the Title Var what I have to match the Value so when I load in a new view I can print the Value by itself.

 Title = "Another Test Cell";
Value = "content<BR><BR>this is contenty";

I am now using: NSArray *kbc = [allKB[@"KnowledgeBaseEntries"] objectAtIndex:0]; to get just one result. IE:

Comment: How do I print the Value from that single KnowledgeBaseEntry

Answer (score 0):

**Parse like this**

```
NSDictionary *dict;
NSString *strAllowBotAccess =[[dict objectForKey:@"KnowledgeBaseEntry"]objectForKey:@"AllowBotAccess"];

NSLog(@"dict=====%@", strAllowBotAccess);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try https://github.com/jsonmodel/jsonmodel
JSONModel allows rapid creation of smart data models. You can use it in your iOS, macOS, watchOS and tvOS apps. Automatic introspection of your model classes and JSON input drastically reduces the amount of code you have to write.

Easy to use, you can parse all keys or some of them.

```
@interface YourModel : JSONModel
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger id;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *value;
@end

@implementation YourModel

+ (JSONKeyMapper *)keyMapper
{
    return [[JSONKeyMapper alloc] initWithModelToJSONDictionary:@{
        @"id": @"Id",
        @"value": @"KnowledgeBaseEntry.Value"
    }];
}

@end
```